# How to get a transaction history by specific transaction ID(txhash) in Corda

Tags: corda

To get state I can use Vault, but what about transactions? How I can get them, for example, by txHash? Is it possible to do this by vaultService.queryBy(criteria) ?

Since internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot method is deprecated now, any ways to retrieve a specific transaction by using txhash as of Corda 4?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the node you can call:

```
serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(hash)
```

Via rpc I think you can do this:

```
proxy.stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingSnapshot().map { it.transactionId }.first { it == hash }
```

But a better solution would be to create a flow that takes in a hash, calls the first snippet and returns the transaction.